# Prototype Ajax Update Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, pylons

I am working with Prototype while using the pylons framework and trying to make an Ajax call.

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action = "javascript:void(0)" onsubmit = "new Ajax.Updater('graph','/saffron_main/click_out_display'); ">

    <label for="tids">Select Relevant Tids</label>

    <select id="tids" multiple="multiple" name="tids" title="Tids">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <p><input class = "button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>


<div id = "graph">

</div>
```

I can see that the my controller gets called and a http request gets made to /saffron_main/click_out_display. Everything looks like it is working properly. The only problem is the div never gets populated. I am pulling out my hair trying to figure this one out and any helps would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you put a `return false;` inside the onsubmit after you instantiate an `Ajax.Updater` ?

Why -
It currently would be returning true by default and the page may be getting posted back, not via Ajax

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean return false? Sorry I am new to all this.

Comment: I added return false and nothing changed.